# Is there a way to do a millisecond level delay in matlab?

Tags: matlab, delay

Help for 'PAUSE' says

```
PAUSE(n) pauses for n seconds before continuing, where n can also be a
fraction. The resolution of the clock is platform specific. Fractional
pauses of 0.01 seconds should be supported on most platforms.
```

But in my case pause(0.01) doesn't do anything at all (pause, pause(n) with whole number n works)

Is there any way to make a millisecond level delay (50 ms, 100 ~ 500 ms) delay in matlab?

Matlab version is

```
MATLAB Version 7.9.0.529 (R2009b)
```

64 bit on a Windows 10 64 bit Home edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options. Let's call them *the looping option* and *the native option*. The first is just using a while loop to check if your desired time to wait is already reached. You can do this with MATLAB's stopwatch timer [`tic`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) and [`toc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html). This is the normal time (not the CPU-time). As you are writing a loop, which runs at maximum speed, you might encounter a high CPU-usage but this should be OK if it is only for a couple of milliseconds.

```
%% looping
% desired time to wait
dt_des = 0.001; % 1 ms
% initialize clock
t_st = tic;
% looping
while toc(t_st) < dt_des
end
% read clock
toc(t_st)
```

The *native option* is using [`pause`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html) (make sure that you have enabled it once with `pause('on')`). I assumed from your question that this does not always work -- however, it does on my system (R2019b, windows 10).

```
%% use pause()
tic
pause(0.001)
toc
```

The results of both are

```
Elapsed time is 0.001055 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.001197 seconds.
```

It's not too accurate but you might get better results if you tune the numbers on your PC.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use

```
java.lang.Thread.sleep(10);
```

if you are using an old matlab version, see discussion [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/pause-for-the-better).